# Execute javascript function in chain of button clicks

Tags: javascript, html, button

On my original post I wasn't for sure on the amount of depth I should go to. Here is what I have been working on since the jQuery answer was posted:

I am attempting to execute a task which requires the user to choose and click one html button out of a series of buttons and then be required to choose another html button out of a series of buttons.

Essentially I would like the value of the first button selection to be passed as a parameter to a function that will run when the user clicks the second button. I'm just learning javascript and I'm lost.

Thank you

HTML:

```
<form id="scoreboard">
<div>
<input type="text" name="homeTeam" value="00" size="2"  "readonly" id="homeTeamScore"/>
<input type="button" value="+1" name="add1" id="homeAdd1" class="homeScore" onClick="calcScore(1)"/>
<input type="button" value="-1" name="neg1" id="homeNeg1" class="homeScore" onClick="calcScore(4)"/>
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" name="homeP1" id="homeP1" class="player" value="24" style="text-align:center;"/>
<input type="text" name="homeP1Score" value="0" size="2" style="text-align:center;"/>
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" name="homeP2" id="homeP2" class="player" value="44" style="text-align:center;"/>
<input type="text" name="homeP2Score" value="0" size="2" style="text-align:center;"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function calcScore(amount) {
if(amount==1) {scoreboard.homeP1Score.value++;scoreboard.homeTeam.value++;}
else if(amount==4) {scoreboard.homeP1Score.value--;scoreboard.homeTeam.value--;}
}

$('.player').click(function() {
//initialize the second button listener
var data = $(this).attr('data');
$('.homeScore').click(function() {
    function addHomeScore(data)
});
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to define a function parameter from a specific button being clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
    //initialize the second button listener
    var data = $(this).attr('data');
    $('#button2Id').click(function() {
        yourFunction(data);
    });
 });
```

This method is better because it uses JavaScript scoping to avoid globals. Since JavaScript (especially with jQuery) sometimes has multiple threads/functions executing at the same time, it's very easy to run into problems with globals. They're also very hard to test and unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

#### In raw JavaScript:

***HTML:***

```
 <button class="button1" onclick="saveValue()" />
 <button class="button2" onclick="callMethod()" />
```

***JavaScript:***

```
 myGlobalVariable = null;
 function saveValue(){
       myGlobalVariable = "Value That Was Selected";
 }

 function callMethod(){
       alert(myGlobalVariable + "I HAZ ACCESS TO GLOBALS!!!!");
 }
```

---

#### In jQuery:

***HTML:***

```
     <button class="button1" />
     <button class="button2" />
```

***JavaScript:***

```
     myGlobalVariable = null;
     $('button.button1').click(function(){
             myGlobalVariable = "Value That Was Selected";
     });
     $('button.button2').click(function(){
            alert(myGlobalVariable + "I HAZ ACCESS TO GLOBALS!!!!");
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

setup some global variable in js. then on each button setup some onClick events that go and change the global var. then the next button click can check to see the value in the global var

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```